# Ethernet adapter fails after suspend

Tags: windows-10, networking, ethernet, wake-up, suspend

I just buyed a new PC and the Ethernet adapter fails after wake up from suspend mode.

OS Windows 10 Home

Motherboard Asus B450-F RogStrix

Ryzen 5 1600

The onboard adapter is an Intel I211.
Windows 10 successfully repairs the connection but I must to do it every time I wake up the PC.
In my previous PC with W7 x64 this never happens, Is this a W10 thing or is Intel driver bug?
How I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Device issues surrounding power state change are nearly always driver-caused.

So, you start by getting the latest drivers for your system, especially the one for the device that is having issues. If that doesn't resolve the issue, because it is a new computer, you contact the manufacturer for warranty support.

Comment: I just updated suspended for 20 seconds and seems to work ok, I will check later for a longer suspend period.

Comment: It just did it again. I can believed.